# Identify position in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, position

I have a foreach loop and I need to identify the position of the single items. The items are always 9. I use this code. Someone has a more elegant solution?

```
<?php
    foreach( $fruit as $key => $apple ); 
?>
    <li class="<?php if( ($key == 0) || ($key == 3) || ($key == 6) ) echo 'first'; if( ($key == 1) || ($key == 4) || ($key == 7) ) echo 'middle'; if( ($key == 2) || ($key == 5) || ($key == 8) ) echo 'last'; ?>"
          //stuff
     </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Modulo of 3 gives you 0,1,2 Start, Middle and End

Comment: Hi Tony, could you post an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per commented request though PHP is a language I've done little more than potter with

```
<?php foreach( $fruit as $key => $apple ); ?>
      <?php $position = $key % 3; ?>     
    <li class="<?php if( $position == 0) echo 'first'; 
                     if( $position == 1) echo 'middle'; 
                     if( $position == 2) echo 'last'; ?>"
          //stuff
     </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

% is the remainder from integer division

```
0 / 3 = 0 remainder 0
1 / 3 = 0 remainder 1
2 / 3 = 0 remainder 2
3 / 3 = 1 remainder 0
...
8 / 3 = 2 remainder 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the original position, you should most likely be using a `for` loop rather than a `foreach`. You can also get rid of the length logic statement by using the modulo operator.

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fruit); $i++) {
        $apple = $fruit[i];
        $remainder = $i % 3
?>

    <li class="<?php 
        if($remainder == 0) echo 'first';
        if($remainder == 1) echo 'middle';
        if($remainder == 2) echo 'last'; ?>"

    // stuff

    </li>

<?php } ?>
```